# C# Downloading files from Google Cloud and facing this error (HttpStatusCode is not found. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException)

Tags: c#, json, google-cloud-platform, http-status-codes

I have been trying to upload and download files to and from google cloud .

```
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           

            string bucketName = "uploads";

            // Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key file.
            GoogleCredential credential = null;
            using (var jsonStream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open,
                FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(jsonStream);
            }
            var storageClient = StorageClient.Create(credential);

            //using (var fileStream = new FileStream("C:\\...", FileMode.Open,
            //    FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            //{
            //    storageClient.UploadObject(bucketName, "file1", "text/plain", fileStream);
            //}
            //List objects
            foreach (var obj in storageClient.ListObjects(bucketName, ""))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
            }

            // Download file
            using (var fileStream = File.Create("C:\\...))
            
            {
                storageClient.DownloadObject(bucketName, "myfile.csv", fileStream);
```

> It works fine with uploading and showing what files i have in the cloud bucket. But i am getting this error for downloading files.Unhandled Exception: Google.GoogleApiException: The service storage has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is NotFound. No error message was specified. ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error parsing NaN value. Path '', line 1, position 1.
> [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s8OE.png)

Any possible solution ?

I tried looking up if that happened to anyone but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Please provide the file stack trace *as text* in the question - we can't tell which operation has failed at the moment.

Comment: Fundamentally though, it sounds like you're trying to download a file that doesn't exist. (The JSON parsing error is unexpected, admittedly.)

Comment: The `Path '', line 1, position 1` in the error generally means ‘this isn’t Json’ but yes, why it should try and parse a 404 is.. odd.

Comment: .. unless I suppose it’s trying to parse an error message expressed as Json, which `DeserializeErrorAsync` suggests might be the case

Comment: @stuartd: Yes, most of the time API errors *do* come with associated JSON. Sometimes it's HTML though, and sometimes there's nothing. (And it's hard to predicate that, so we try to parse everything.) I'm not sure what input is causing Json.NET to think it's a NaN though.